# What is wrong with my code for creating a table in a MYSQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE Persons(FirstName VARCHAR(30),
    Lastname VARCHAR(30), AGE INT)PRIMARY KEY (Firstname)"; 
    mysql_select_db('strsmi_database');
    $query = "(mysql_query($sql, $con)";


    if (! $query)
    {
      echo ("Could Not Create Table: " . Smysqli_error());
    }
    else    
    {
    echo ("Table Created");
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

My output said that it had created the table but when I went into PHP Myadmin no table had been created.

Comment: Why is `$query = "(mysql_query($sql, $con)";` in quotes?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/www/stjohnstone.info/index.php on line 20

Comment: This is just some basic typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closing paren after `int` should be a comma and the closing paren should go at the end.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    FirstName VARCHAR(30),
    Lastname VARCHAR(30),
    AGE INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Firstname)
   );
```

EDIT:

You can see this work on SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c90646).

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/www/stjohnstone.info/index.php on line 20

Comment: Thanks that fixed code. Great quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

`if (!$query)` will evaluate as false since `$query` is a string.

its the same as `if (!isset($query))`

remove the quotes and outer parenthesis from `$query = "(mysql_query($sql, $con)";`

Also I recommend against using `mysql_` functions. they're depreciated and will be removed in future versions.

you should use `mysqli_` or `pdo` (my preference due to prepared statements)